# Removing duplicate values after pandas.groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to group three columns in a dataset using the `str.join` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'company', 'This', 'Them', 'Those Guys'],
                   [2,'agency', 'That', 'Other', 'These Guys'],
                   [2, 'agency', 'This', 'Them', 'Those Guys'],
                   [1, 'company', 'It', 'They', 'Those Guys']],
                  columns=['Acct', 'AcctName', 'Dude', 'Boss', 'Area'])

g = df.groupby(by=['Acct', 'AcctName'])

pd.concat([g['Dude'].apply('/'.join),
           g['Boss'].apply('/'.join),
           g['Area'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(sorted(set(x))))],
          axis=1).reset_index()
```

This produces the expected result in my test data:

```
 Acct   AcctName    Dude    Boss    Area
0   1   company This/It Them/They   Those Guys
1   2   agency  That/This   Other/Them  These Guys/Those Guys
```

But when I copy this code to the actual report I'm building, the "Area" column has the equivalent of `Those Guys/Those Guys`. It's not removing the duplicate data.

I tried adding `df['Area'] = df['Area'].transform(str.strip)`
before grouping the dataframe but that doesn't solve the issue (extra spaces are the bane of my data processing life!).

Any ideas how I could do this better or figure out what's wrong with the data?

Comment: Josh, what's the expected output?

Comment: To only have ```Those Guys``` in the final data. The problem has been solved and I don't think it had anything to do with the data.

Comment: Can you post an answer on how you solved it, i'm interested

Comment: I just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mea culpa. Again. Purely a naming issue on my part.

I am doing my development in a Juypter notebook and read the data in one cell, then in a later cell I was doing the actual processing. That particular cell did the grouping and concatenation.

What did I not do? Give the concatenated dataframe a new name. So it was working from the beginning, **but because I was using the same variable name**, the value of `Those Guys/Those Guys` was in a single cell of the dataframe, not being generated from the values in the dataframe.

Lesson learned. Again.

Comment: Thanks Josh, understanding the issue helps me as well when solving these

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.agg()`instead of `.apply()`:

```py
pd.concat([g['Dude'].agg('/'.join),
           g['Boss'].agg('/'.join),
           g['Area'].agg(lambda x: '/'.join(sorted(set(x))))],
          axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks. That does work, but I think the problem was more to do with the fact that I am working in a Jupyter notebook and the data caching was probably messing with me.